# White line appearing under selected tab title in react-tabs library

Tags: css, reactjs, react-tabs

I'm using the `react-tabs` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabs) and I have applied custom styling, but I'm facing an issue where a white line appears under the selected tab title when it is clicked. The strange thing is that the line disappears when I click somewhere else on the page.

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-tab-border-error-3z3mh4)

[image: White line appears under Tab 3 which is currently active]

Below is the CSS code for the tabs:

```css
.react-tabs__tab {
   background-color: inherit;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 50px;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 10px;
}

.react-tabs__tab:hover {
   color: #0099ff;
   transition: 0.3s;
}

.react-tabs__tab--selected {
   color: #0099ff;
   border: 1px solid #0099ff;
   border-bottom: none; /* Updated line */
}

.react-tabs__tab:focus {
   outline: none;
}

.react-tabs__tab:focus:after {
   content: none;
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `border-bottom: none` line, the white line disappears: https://nimb.ws/ltJdCw

Comment: It's  not a white  line, it's the absence of a border at the bottom as @m4n0 has mentioned. It appears to have been deliberately set to none - do you know why?

Comment: @m4n0 got it. I firsly tried by removing bottom, and then added this focus and focus:after part.
However, I forgot to double-check if the bottom part was removed after that. Thank you for pointing that out, and I appreciate your help.